# How do I use android to write a file that is immediately accessible from a connected Windows PC

Tags: java, android

I am creating a zip file [like this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29) on an micro-SD card (FAT-32) connected to an android device (Motorola Xoom MZ601, Android 4.0.3) .

When I use USB to connect the device to a Windows PC in "media device" mode I find that my newly created files are not displayed in Windows Explorer.

Things that do not work:

- Refreshing Windows Explorer (F5).
- Physically disconnecting then reconnecting the USB cable.
- Broadcasting a [`Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) for the new file.
- [`File.canRead()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canRead%28%29) and [.canWrite()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#canWrite%28%29) return true, while [`File.setReadable(true,false)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setWritable%28boolean,%20boolean%29) is returning false.

Things that do work:

- Power cycling the device
- Removing the SD card from the device then using an SD-USB adapter to connect it to the PC.

I would like for users to be able to plug the device directly into the PC for immediate access to their files, without needing to shut down and/or pull the card out.

Any advice on achieving this goal?

Comment: I'm not really sure what's the problem, but have you tried adding the `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` to your `FileOutputStream` initialization?
Here's a link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Comment: @NitroNbg Thanks for tip, but it looks like `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is only applicable to `Context.openFileOutput`, and that method won't accept arbitrary paths.